# Reading array values as user input gives wrong array length and only -a or -p works in read

Tags: bash, shell-script, array, read

Problem 1:
I want to get the array items as user inputs at runtime; print the items and print the array length. This is what I have:

```
read -a myarray
echo "array items" ${myarray[@]}
echo "array length" ${#myarray[@]}
```

At runtime, I gave the following as input,

```
$ ("apple fruit" "orange" "grapes")
```

The output was,

```
array items "apple fruit" "orange" "grapes"
array length 4
```

which is not correct.

If I don't ask for user input and instead used an array declared and initialised as part of the code as `myarray=("apple fruit" "orange" "grapes")` the array length is echoed as 3. So, It seems like my usage of read command is not right.

Problem 2:
If I add a prompt to the read command as follows,

```
read -p "enter array items: " myarray
```

the first item "apple fruit" gets printed as fruit" and the length is also wrong.

If I remove the prompt and add -a, everything is good. If I combine both a and p and give it as read -ap, prompt doesn't popup at all. It waits for values without any message. Why is it so? Can someone explain to me what is wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem 1:

In your example, `read` does not get its input from a command line argument, but from stdin.  As such, the input it receives does not go through `bash`'s string parser.  Instead, it is treated as a literal string, delimited by spaces.  So with your input, your array values become:

```
[0]->("apple
[1]->fruit"
[2]->"orange"
[3]->"grapes"
```

To do what you want, you need to escape any spaces you have, to avoid the delimiter from kicking in.  Namely, you must enter the following input after invoking `read`:

```
apple\ fruit oranges grapes
```

---

Problem 2: In order for `read` to store the input it receives as an array, you must have an `-a` switch followed by the array name.  So you need:

```
read -a myarray -p "Enter your items"
```

Comment: I thought that giving the items within quotes protects the space and treats the input 'apple fruit' as one single item. Thank you very much for explaining  it all!

Comment: Put another way, standard input is not subject to shell processing. With something like `IFS=: read -a arr <<<"a:b:c"`, it is the `read` command *itself* which splits the single line `a:b:c` into three separate elements, rather than it somehow reading three elements `a`, `b`, and `c` from its input.

Comment: @Alex Thank you! I experimented it with `mkdir "abc def" `
Like you said, the space was protected since mkdir is an exteral command. I also tried `cd "abc def" ` and expected an error since cd is a shell builtin. But, the space was still protected and the command went through.

Comment: @Ammu The difference is, the `"abc def"` is getting parsed *as a command line argument*, and not getting its input from `stdin`.

Answer (score 3):

The shell's command line parser cares about double and single quotes but `read` doesn't (thus it does not remove them, too). For `read` input you need backslashes:

```
apple\ fruit orange grapes
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to let the user use shell quoting to delimit the elements (and not only `backslash`), in `zsh`, you could do:

```
IFS= read -r 'string?Please enter the elements: '
array=("${(@XQ)${(z)string}}")
```

- `(z)` is to split `$string` into elements like the shell parser would do.
- `Q` to remove one level of quoting from the resulting words
- `X` to report error messages in the syntax
- `@` and the quotes to preserve empty elements.

That way, the user can enter things like:

```
'first word' "second word" third\ word $'word\nwith\nnewline' ''
```

Beware that, while there is no expansion being done, the syntax of the shell code that is expected is not limited to quoting. For instance, `$(foo bar)` would be parsed into a single `$(foo bar)` word, `${unclosed` would cause a syntax error. The user would need to enter them as `'$(foo)' 'bar)'`, or `'${unclosed'.